# proper syntax to delete default route for a particular interface?

Tags: networking, route, network-interface

**summary:**

```
me@client:~$ sudo route del default ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del default dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default gw 10.144.15.234 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.144.15.234 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default gw 0.0.0.0 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 0.0.0.0 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
```

**details:**

I'm trying to debug a VPN-related misconfiguration on a laptop (call it "the client") which is running

```
me@client:~$ cat /etc/debian_version
jessie/sid
me@client:~$ uname -rv
3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.8-1 (2013-11-13)
me@client:~$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (Debian 4.8.2-1) 4.8.2
me@client:~$ sudo route --version
[sudo] password for tlroche: 
net-tools 1.60
route 1.98 (2001-04-15)
+NEW_ADDRT +RTF_IRTT +RTF_REJECT +I18N
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE 
HW:  +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL -TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB +EUI64
```

On this client, I have started an OpenVPN client (after previously starting an OpenVPN server in the cloud), logged into a remote-access website, and used that site's web UI to connect to a (proprietary) F5 SSL VPN (which I want to tunnel through the OpenVPN). (More details on the design goal [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-intended-solution) and the problem configuration [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/linode_jumpbox_config/wiki/Home#rst-header-networking-problem).) This produces

```
me@client:~$ date ; sudo ifconfig
Thu Jan 22 11:48:43 EST 2015
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <omitted/>
          inet addr:192.168.1.142  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: <omitted/>
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10224715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6011530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12886933501 (12.0 GiB)  TX bytes:677423768 (646.0 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2600000-f2620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:497 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:51273 (50.0 KiB)  TX bytes:51273 (50.0 KiB)

# Note I get slightly different IP#s for interface=ppp0 each time I run this scenario.

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.144.15.234  P-t-P:10.144.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:56 (56.0 B)  TX bytes:2418 (2.3 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:304 (304.0 B)  TX bytes:304 (304.0 B)

me@client:~$ date ; sudo route -n
Thu Jan 22 11:48:48 EST 2015
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.144.15.100   128.0.0.0       UG    1      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.144.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
128.0.0.0       10.144.15.100   128.0.0.0       UG    1      0        0 ppp0
134.67.15.30    10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 tun0
```

Once at that point, I'm directed (IIUC) to delete the default route being set by the F5VPN (on interface=`ppp0`, for debugging. Furthermore, I need to do this quickly, because (and this is the problem with the current misconfiguration) the misconfiguration causes the OpenVPN tunnel to fail quickly, which breaks the situation I want to debug.

Hence it is quite infuriating that I cannot seem to find the correct `route` syntax to do this:

```
me@client:~$ sudo route del default ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del default dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default gw 10.144.15.234 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.144.15.234 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default gw 0.0.0.0 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process

me@client:~$ sudo route del -net default netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 0.0.0.0 dev ppp0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
```

`info route` is not helping, nor are my websearches finding helpful doc. (Both cases probably due to my lack of networking experience.) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the routing table you have included in your question, you do not have a default route pointing to `ppp0`, so that's why you can't delete it. ("No such process" here means "No such route").

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.144.15.100   128.0.0.0       UG    1      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

That's a route to 0.0.0.0/1 (NOT a default route, a default route is 0.0.0.0/0) pointing to 10.144.15.100 which uses `ppp0`, plus a default route pointing to 192.168.1.1 which goes out `eth0`.

By the way, on Linux, you should use the `ip` command instead of `ifconfig`, `route`, and others. The syntax and output formats used by `ip` are much more intuitive and easy to understand and use.

You should be able to see the above two routes (and all the others) with `ip route` and delete them with, respectively:

```
ip route del 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.144.15.100
ip route del default via 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `ip route` and to [tty1.net](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison_en.html) for teaching me about `ip link`. I am definitely finding those easier to use and parse!

Comment: Note also followup question (regarding latency observed in route deletion) [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180684/delay-in-ip-route-deletion).

Comment: thanks, you can get routes via a `route` command or a `ip route list` command,

and using also the interface 'dev' clause  `sudo ip route delete default via 182.18.1.1 dev tun0`